# Natural Language Processing Algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

I am planning on developing a Natural Language Question System using NLP.
I have performed literature study regarding the possible algorithms which are applicable for a NLQ System.

The end-user should, after finishing the tool, be able to ask a question to the system, which on its turn gives an answer in the form of a table of will visualize the answer in the form of a graph.

Furthermore, the answering part is already finished. Programming will happen in Python, using the PyNLPl library.

The main tool can already perform mathematical operations and summarizes the outcome of these operations. The user should be able to ask questions as:

- "How were the sales on a rainy day in the month january?"
- "What is the amount of ... of the whole of Europe"

This question is not meant to be subjective, as I mentioned before, I did literature study.
I made a proper selection of the list of algorithms which I found. And am left with a decision of:

- POST, Chunking, Named Entity Extraction
- Parsing
- Topic Modeling and keyword extraction.

Algorithms per bullet point would be:

- Conditional Random Fields - Hidden Markov Model
- CKY Algorithm  - Earley Algorithm
- Latend Dirichlet Allocation

Furthermore, the variables which should be mentioned in the questions, are not independent. Is Naive Bayes in that case also applicable?
The chosen algorithm, should outperform the rest of the algorithms and make the best fit.

Comment: Seems like you are on the right track. You know what you want, and you have an idea of what to accomplish. But you should reconsider the way you asked this "question" instead of just putting your whole "Assignment" here, you should ask more pointed questions about your work, don't forget to include reasons and constraints to what you *question* is about. Ideally, you would want to ask a number of questions that each dealt with a different part of your "assignment" first narrowing down what kind of approach you even should be using for your assignment, then figuring out what algorithm, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! Do you think it is smart to remove the algorithms in that case? I will change it right away..

Comment: This question is right fit in artificial intelligence community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been reading and reading, and found answers to almost all my questions.
I am sticking to Early algorithm as it offers a dynamic programming approach (CKY does the same). 
Both algorithms are chart parsing algorithms.

Earley is a context free -, top-down parsing algorithm. Which makes it a goal driven algorithm. From start symbol down. Furthermore, it is more efficient than the CKY algorithm.
Slides of comparison, and explanation:
https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~michaluz/seminar/CKY1.pdf

Note: Earley and CKY parsing algorithms will only result in a parse tree with which nothing can be done.
However, Using e.g. shift-reduce dependency parsing algorithm does not only give the dependencies between verious words in addition to parsing and calidating the sentence structure, these dependencies can also be used for relation extraction in the question. In order to really understand the question.